# Can I short circuit DNS round robin in a browser?

Tags: domain-name-system

Under normal conditions the web server is load-balanced across multiple IP addresses. This is served by DNS as a list of IP addresses and picked at random by the browser.
In my case I want to force a specific IP address in this list while opening the URL in the browser.
Is there a way to force a certain IP address ?

Comment: Do you have possibility to edit the hosts file manually?

Comment: Indeed I tried this and it works. Just wondering if there was any other way in the browser to do the same.

Comment: That is the most simple way, especially if you use a GUI like Hosts File Editor to edit the file visually

Answer (score 1):

## Edit the `hosts` file

That is the most *canonical* way to force a desired IP address to resolve a DNS name.

Of course, it works only on the same machine used to browse the website, e.g. this solution applies to *final user*, not *web developer*.

Obviously, you must resolve the desired IP earlier, and you must make sure the IP does not *exit* the pool, which likely happens on cloud services.